# Installing any linux on Highpoint Rocketraid 1740

Tags: system-installation, raid

I have a server that has a highpoint rocketraid 1740 controller and would like to install any kind of Linux (free version, not Red Hat paid) on it. I tried installing the latest Debian but the installer sees the individual disks, not the RAID.

Any advice on this?

Comment: For gentoo linux, there is a description at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/HighPoint_RocketRAID. As your debian installation recognizes the controller, maybe you only need the additional software mentioned.Or you have to build the kernel module ifit is not available (rr174x)

Comment: For the maintainer, see http://danweeks.net/p-opensource

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have a look and see if I can get something to work.

Comment: Seems like this controller is a FakeRAID and a really old one at that so I am thinking about using software RAID instead.

Comment: This will be the best decision, as those RAID drivers might fail after updates (had that problem years ago). Depending on what you are wanting to do with the server, you could try with md/lvm or ZFS (which I'ld prefer, but that's a very personal opinion).